# In Java, Is it possible to return more than one value from try catch block?

Tags: java, try-catch

I want to read the Id, name and score from console for another use. However these three variables are inside try-catch block scope. I wonder if there is any way I can get these three values return from try-catch.(**If I don't want to put the three variables individually in three pairs of try-catch block**) Thanks for the time.

Here is my sample code:

```
    StuManage sm = new StuManage();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Please enter the student ID: ");
    try {
        String Id = br.readLine();
        String name = br.readLine();
        float score =Float.parseFloat(br.readLine());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: You can encapsulate those three values into an object.  Your idea sounds like a very bad one.

Comment: At least one of those three resulted in an exception. This may mean that the method was not successful. Reporting (e.g., to diagnostic logging) the values you did read successfully might be useful in the catch. But anything that depends on successfully reading those three values should occur inside the `throw` block, rather than in the catch or after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Just declare the method as `throws IOException` and remove the try catch altogether.

Comment: How about not throwing those exceptions?

Comment: It's a bad idea to abdicate responsibility for an exception at the point of interruption. Some methods can reasonably throw a checked exception, but the ones that receive it are not in that category. At the very, very least log the exception and leave the method; the foolish `e.printStackTrace();` idiom is a weird trope. So then what happens? Presumably the following code relies on the result, now invalid, and will thus have bugs because the `catch` block didn't actually fulfill its responsibility to actually _catch_ the exception, not just drop it.

Answer (score 2):

yes , you can declare and initialize those to an invalid value

```
 String id = null;
 String name = null;
 float score = 1.0f;
 try {
       id = br.readLine();
       name = br.readLine();
       score = Float.parseFloat(br.readLine());
 } catch (IOException e) {
```

then you need to check after that try block which values are still holding and invalid initial value...

Comment: Be advised that while this is possible and certainly often done it is a anti-pattern if you have to check variables after a try/catch. The risk of incomplete sate is quite high. It usually asks for more encapsulation or handling the exceptions in a different place.

Comment: It's better to write methods to exit with a default upon an exception, in most use cases.

Comment: @LewBloch which Convention do you think is violated?

Comment: It was `Id` as a variable name, which someone edited after I posted my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Just ensure that the variables are declared global to the method with their default values, that way it should be fine to access them throughout the method.

Another solution would be to remove the `try/catch` from the method and rather put the `try/catch` within the `main` method, that way you'll let the exception(s)(if any) bubble up to the main method and then handle them there, which you'll also benefit from because you no longer need to worry about scoping issues.

Comment: Default values are in most cases nonexistent or inappropriate to the object model. Exceptions when caught are meant to interrupt the flow. A usual idiom is to simply catch and log the exception, close any ancillary resources, then exit the method. "Global to the method" means instance or class state, almost certainly overkill. How about merely "in larger scope than the try-catch block"?

Answer (score -3):

Easily you can't, Because try and catch block is for check block of code for errors, Because of that the block of code should't be accessible outside the try block to be truly tested.